# Can I move InitializeComponent() to Loaded()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, uwp

Dependency property setter isn't being called in app constructor and values are only available after user control is loaded. So, is it safe to move the `InitializeComponent()` method to the `Loaded()` method?

Comment: Not necessarily safe, no. `Loaded` gets called after the constructor is finished, so what gives you the impression putting it in `Loaded` will fix your problem?

Comment: What is your DP doing that requires this behavior?

Comment: For starters, it works when I put it in `Loaded()`.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT DP just has some strings. I need those strings to properly initialize a class. Strange thing is, if this initialization is done in `Loaded` (without `InitializeComponent`) the controls aren't rendered at all.

Comment: Properties set in XAML are always set after the constructor is called (that's the way objects work). It's still not clear why you need the values in the constructor. Can you rely on default values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps with your problem, but I just let the VisualStateManger Goto it's current state in the Loaded Event:

```
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, YourStateGroup.CurrentState.Name, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `InitializeComponent()` where it is. Instead, use the Loaded event. i.e.

```
  [Dependency]
  public Foo Foo { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

  private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Propery injection should have taken place now, so do what you need to do with them
        }
```

Comment: You'll want to remove the `Loaded` handler as soon as it is raised, to avoid doing the work multiple times if the control is unloaded and re-loaded (eg, re-parented).